# Issue with Html Agility Pack (HAP) when 3 slashes in arrow appear in JSON Code

Tags: json, html-agility-pack

I have a JSON object that contain HTML used to display rich text. The issue I found is when there is three slashes ("///") in a row HAP decodes it in a way that is no longer valid JSON.

For Example - C# code

```
 var jsonText = $"{{\"htmlAddress\": \"<a href =\\\"www.stackoverflow.com\">stackoverflow}}";
 var doc2 = new HtmlDocument();
 doc2.LoadHtml(jsonText);
```

The result of that is

`OuterHtml = "<a href=\"\\&quot;www.stackoverflow.com&quot;\">stackoverflow</a>"`

The above source JSON may look funny at first but I believe it is correct since we have to escape all of the quotation marks with slashes. The first of the 3 slashes escapes the actual slash that needs to stay, and the third one is to escape the quotation mark.

When this code is run through JSON.parse() in javascript it fails. Any suggestions on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Using the HtmlEntity.DeEntitize(stringHere) will remove things like \&quot; and insert an actual quote. With this new knowledge

`OuterHtml = "<a href=\"\\&quot;www.stackoverflow.com&quot;\">stackoverflow</a>"`

would turn into something like 

`<a href="\"www.stackoverflow.com"">stackoverflow</a>`

which is still not right

Comment: Not sure what you're expecting here. Just look at the string itself, it's not even valid json. So you should check that first before worrying about how HAP processes it. `{"htmlAddress": "<a href =\"www.stackoverflow.com">stackoverflow}`

Comment: @Nick2618 same problem i facing now, any solutions found